# Formatting edits

Tags: feature-request

I rarely edit questions, but I finally tried to improve this one today: [How to format Start + End Dates without using PHP](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61085/how-to-format-start-end-dates-without-using-php)

The question had an example, which was not formatted to be displayed literally, and so the line break didn't display.  In the original question, it sounded like the user wanted the date to display like this:

1 May 2012 2-3 May 2012

but could only get this:

2 May 2012 - 3 May 2012

After reading and re-reading, I realized it was a formatting issue, and tried to edit the question only for that (it is well-written otherwise: the English is clear).

The system wouldn't let me save my edit, however, even with a substantial comment in fear that I was making a one-character typo fix.

I wonder if this is new.  In any case, could we allow **formatting changes like this through**?  Is that too hard?  I banged my head against the wall to find something else to edit, and changed some language that was inconsequential, but didn't like messing with things that were already ok, just to get the edit accepted.

As soon as my edit went through, I noticed another user leaving a comment because he was confused by the lack of formatting (so I know it was useful)!

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I too found it annoying at times when I was not able to submit a edit because the change was not of 6 characters (atleast). But, I guess the design is such that the edit is considered to be less significant if there isn't a considerable amount of change. On that note, I would like to mention that once you have [enough privilege](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) you'll be able to make even 1 character edits.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/what-about-lowering-the-edit-character-limit-for-characters-in-code-snippets

Comment: Ooooh.  I actually didn't know that (about the privilege).  I'm not that far away.  Good!  I guess I better go answer questions then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested edits are required to edit at least 6 characters. As far as I remember, if also the title is edited, the restriction is not applied.

The restriction exists mainly because every suggested edit is reviewed from two users (three on *Stack Overflow*); it is preferable to make the suggested edit worth the time spent to review it, and make it as much complete as possible.
The other effect of that restriction is avoiding users gain reputation by making single character edits multiple times.